# django use Case When to compose sql query

Tags: python, django

I have `data` format like this:

```
[
 {
  "name":"abc",
  "number":120,
  "total":500
 },
 {
  "name":"def",
  "number":30,
  "total":400
 }
```

]

and I have a django query logic like this:

```
Table.objects.update(
      number = Case(
          When(name=data[0]['name'], then=Value(data[0]['number'])),
          When(name=data[1]['name'], then=Value(data[1]['number'])),
          When(name=data[2]['name'], then = Value(data[2]['number'])),
          ...
          When(name=data[499]['name'], then = Value(data[499]['number'])),
          default=F('number'),
      )
  )
```

I want to use code to generate the `When` part

so I use list comprehension to generate it,  and then use `','.join(query_list)` to remove the bracket `[` `]`
But here is problem : it said `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, When found`

I can't convert it to string , because `When(name=data[499]['name'], then = Value(data[499]['number'])` should be a object. 
How can I do to fix this???

```
query_list = [When(name=data[i]['name'], then=Value(data[i]['number'])) for i,item in enumerate(data)]

part_of_sql= ','.join(query_list)
print(part_of_sql)


Table.objects.update(
   number=Case(
     part_of_sql, 
     default=F('number'),
   )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try unpack `query_list` when passing it to `Case` with `*` syntax:

```
Case(*query_list, default=F('number')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works `Table.objects.update(number=Case(default=F('number'), *query_list))`